# If condition met, copy row data from specific columns to a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need to look at the value in column AU, row 2 (starting immediately after the header row) and if not blank, copy data from specific columns in the row to a different sheet.

For example, assume `AU2` is not empty, then copy `A2` to `A2`, `D2` to `B2`, `J2` to `C2`, and so on.

Here's where I am so far:

```
Sub copycolumns()

Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long
lastrow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
erow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
wb = ThisWorkbook
ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet Name")
ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet Name2")

For Each Cel In ws1.Range("AU2:AU" & lastrow)

    If IsEmpty(Cel.Value) Then

        For I = 2 To lastrow

            ws1.Cells(I, 2).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 1)
            ws1.Cells(I, 4).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 2)
            ws1.Cells(I, 6).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 3)
            ws1.Cells(I, 7).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 4)
            ws1.Cells(I, 8).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 5)
            ws1.Cells(I, 10).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 6)
            ws1.Cells(I, 11).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 7)
            ws1.Cells(I, 12).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 8)
            ws1.Cells(I, 16).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 9)
            ws1.Cells(I, 20).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 10)
            ws1.Cells(I, 26).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 11)
            ws1.Cells(I, 27).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 12)
            ws1.Cells(I, 28).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 13)
            ws1.Cells(I, 29).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 14)
            ws1.Cells(I, 36).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 15)
            ws1.Cells(I, 37).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 16)
            ws1.Cells(I, 45).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 17)
            ws1.Cells(I, 55).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 18)
            ws1.Cells(I, 59).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 19)
            ws1.Cells(I, 63).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 20)
            ws1.Cells(I, 47).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 21)

            erow = erow + 1

        Next I

    End If

Next

'ws2.Columns().AutoFit

End Sub
```

My idea was to have a separate if statement for each column to be copied so it would copy the data from one column at a time instead of trying to copy specific cell data from a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Below:

```
Sub copycolumns()

Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet Name")
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet Name2")

lastrow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
erow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1

For Each Cel In ws1.Range("AU2:AU" & lastrow)

    If Len(Cel.Value) > 0 Then

        For I = 2 To lastrow

            ws1.Cells(I, 2).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 1)
            ws1.Cells(I, 4).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 2)
            ws1.Cells(I, 6).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 3)
            ws1.Cells(I, 7).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 4)
            ws1.Cells(I, 8).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 5)
            ws1.Cells(I, 10).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 6)
            ws1.Cells(I, 11).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 7)
            ws1.Cells(I, 12).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 8)
            ws1.Cells(I, 16).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 9)
            ws1.Cells(I, 20).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 10)
            ws1.Cells(I, 26).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 11)
            ws1.Cells(I, 27).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 12)
            ws1.Cells(I, 28).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 13)
            ws1.Cells(I, 29).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 14)
            ws1.Cells(I, 36).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 15)
            ws1.Cells(I, 37).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 16)
            ws1.Cells(I, 45).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 17)
            ws1.Cells(I, 55).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 18)
            ws1.Cells(I, 59).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 19)
            ws1.Cells(I, 63).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 20)
            ws1.Cells(I, 47).Copy ws2.Cells(erow, 21)

            erow = erow + 1

        Next I

    End If

Next

'ws2.Columns().AutoFit

    End Sub
```

Currently It should copy the three cells you mentioned in Question. You can add similarly more columns as much as you need.

your loop was a little off in Range, you don't want to run it over the entire column till bottom, will take hell of a time. And you were also missing an `End If`

Comment: I'm getting a runtime issue now... I edited my code at the top to reflect the changes you suggested. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try debugging using F8 and tell me on which line you get the error

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately my data has way too many rows and so excel is crashing, I'm going to have to come at it from a different way.